# Using "replaceObjectAtIndex" for array within array

Tags: iphone, object, multidimensional-array, replace

I have an array within an (mutable) array.  I am trying to replace certain objects with "replaceObjectAtIndex."

I have tried:

```
[[mutableArrayName objectAtIndex:0]replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"TEST"];
```

but I get the following error:

-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e24d70
2011-03-17 17:02:07.008 Contact details[5145:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e24d70'

I tried this as well:

```
    [mutableArrayName replaceObjectAtIndex:[[mutableArrayName objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0] withObject:@"TEST"];
```

but I get the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 16660 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: did you check to make sure an object existed at index 0 in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd approach relies on having 3 arrays instead of 2. 1st approach seems to be fine but I guess you have an `NSArray` inside of an `NSMutableArray` because `NSArray:replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject` does not exist. So ensure that all arrays are mutable.

Comment: BINGO.  Thanks Kay.  I had added an array within the mutable array.  I assumed that doing so made all the objects mutable (duh).  Works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 2):

So as far as I've understood, you have: a mutable array, and within that, you've got more arrays. Now you want to fetch one of those "sub-arrays" and modify it.

In this case the first try is the correct one, except that you've got `NSArray` instances inside your `NSMutableArray`. And you cannot modify those, hence the exception. So you need to make sure you're stuffing `NSMutableArrays` inside your outer `NSMutableArray`. Then the call of your first try will succeed.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust.  Great advice.  I had an array with the mutable.  All working now.